# Which Linux distribution places all applications in /opt?

Tags: directory-structure, distributions

I read on DistroWatch quite a while back that there's a Linux distribution that installs all application files in /opt directory.  However, I do not remember the name of this distribution.  Anyone here know what I'm on about?

Answer (score 1):

I know of only one GNU/Linux distribution which dispenses with the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and installs each application into its own directory structure: [GoboLinux](http://www.gobolinux.org/index.php?page=at_a_glance).

While it doesn’t use `/opt` as the location for installing applications (it uses `/Programs`), it may be the distribution that you’re thinking of.

Comment: Gobo tries to follow the OSX hierarchy, doesn't it?

Comment: @muru According to Wikipedia, Gobo was influenced by NeXTSTEP which also influenced Mac OS X.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan That name does quite ring a bell, but yes, it is the same concept.  Wasn't aware that OS X did the same thing.  I'll install and have a play.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Slackware or Linux From Scratch? I don't know for sure, but apps installed to `/opt` is not that unusual (see
http://www.slackware.com/config/rootdir.php
or
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html).

Also possible that an Admin prefers installing apps from sources that are configured to install under `/opt` by default or such.

I dont know if there is one distro that does specifically install any app just into `/opt`. I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No distribution which follows the FHS (filesystem hierarchy standard) will use `/opt` to install anything. That location is reserved for third-party applications.

Comment: This is wrong. The FHS explicitly permits distributions to install software under `/opt`.

Comment: Not in my reading of the FHS, but maybe I misread. Can you quote the passage?

Comment: [“Distributions may install software in /opt, but must not modify or delete software installed by the local system administrator without the assent of the local system administrator.”](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)

Comment: Okay, I missed that part. You're quoting from a now-outdated version though -- the new version reads [Distributions may install and otherwise manage software in /opt under an appropriately registered subdirectory.](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html). Still, I would consider it bad form, and I think the FHS language supports that.